# Using azure KeyVault in local development

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I have seen other posts on this, but none of the answers seem to work.
I have an azure function app that I am developing locally. It uses an app setting to get username/password from the key vault. When deployed to azure, it works perfectly. But developing locally, it is not grabbing the data from the vault.

So in code, I have this :

```
var password = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PASSWORD", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

I have added my user onto the vault access policy, and added the app identity on there also. Which is why it works in azure.
I saw this post that mentions setting an environment variable :
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3907
I tried that, but still no dice. Whenever I call the above code, I just get the setting key back, which looks like this :

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/PASSWORD/e97ba4bf3e2e4919b1899384ea349999)
```

Answer (score 9):

Of course, it will not work, the [keyvault reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references) is just the feature of function app or web app, it does not apply to the local development.

In local, your option is to get the secret via the [SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets) manually.

```
var client = new SecretClient(vaultUri: new Uri(keyVaultUrl), credential: new DefaultAzureCredential());    
secret = client.GetSecret("secret-name");
```

The code above uses [`DefaultAzureCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet) of [`Azure.Identity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity?view=azure-dotnet) to auth, it will try several credential types to auth in order, one of them is [`VisualStudioCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.visualstudiocredential?view=azure-dotnet), means it will use the user account logged in the VS to auth, you can also use `VisualStudioCredential` instead of `DefaultAzureCredential` directly in the code.

Besides, the code will also work when you deploy it to Azure, because `DefaultAzureCredential` will use `ManagedIdentityCredential` to auth i.e. use MSI to get the secret(essentially the keyvault reference feature also uses MSI to get the secret), so you can also use it directly rather than this feature, they all depend on yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Functions local development allows usage of KeyVault references via `local.settings.json`. Where all application configuration variables can be set under `'Values'`.The function tools will handle references to `@Microsoft.KeyVault(<password-secret-path>)` and the application will have the values fetched during runtime.

AFAIK this does not work the same for Azure App Services

See:

- [Local settings file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-local#local-settings-file)
- [Source Application Settings from Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#source-application-settings-from-key-vault)

Comment: This actually works. Tested on local. Thank you.